# Issue regarding Anagram in c++

Tags: c++

My below-mentioned code in c++ seems to have a logical error. Please can someone check? Like if I take s1='abc' and s2='abfgh'. 1st for loop, each element of s1 is checked with s2, and the value of count is 2 
2nd for loop, each element of s2 is checked with s1, and the value of count is 4 now. So I can use 's1.length() + s2.length() -count' as the final answer I suppose.

> ```
> #include<iostream>
> #include<string>
> using namespace std;
> int main(){
>
>     string s1;
>     string s2;
>     int test_case,count;
>
>     cin>>test_case;
>     while(test_case!=0){
>         count=0;
>
>         cin>>s1;
>         cin>>s2;
>
>         for(auto l1:s1){
>             for(auto l2:s2){
>                 if(l1==l2){
>                     count+=1;
>                 }
>             }
>
>         }
>
>         for(auto p2:s2){
>             for(auto p1:s1){
>                 if(p2==p1){
>                     count+=1;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         test_case--;
>         cout<<endl;
>     }
>
>     cout<<count;
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: Please step through your code line by line with a debugger and describe us what problems you see in what exact place in your code.

Comment: What do you do about multiple letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad coding practice.

You have a better solution by using a histogram. What means histogram? Histogram is where you put the frequency of found characters in an array. You should put the characters from the first string in the array like this:

```
arr['a'-'0']++
```

or in your case:

```
arr[s1[i]-'0']++
```

then when you loop the second string, you just take one of the count and if it goes under 0, you should print not anagram

```
arr[s2[i]-'0']--;
```